# background and phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, background

I have some problems with my background on phonegap

I have a samsung galaxy tab 2 and it works fine on it but on my htc wildfire I have problems
There you have my css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-page{
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: MankSans;
    background-position:fixed;
    background-color:#102a3e;
}
```

On the htc there are a little white space at the bottom of the screen, but my background-size in auto 100%.

Second problem, the background is not fixed when I scroll the background stay at the top and I have a white background.
I try to add a color but I always have the white screen

Thanks  for your help